# Target CSS ONLY within a certain ID

Tags: css

I am trying to style a particular CSS element where it shows on one page, but not on another.

On the desired page I have something like

```
<div id="home-posts">
   <div class="irrelevantClass">
      <div id="irrelevantID">
         <div class="ClassToTarget">
            Some content
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have CSS that looks like:

```
#anID .ClassToTarget {
   color:#666666;
}
```

This works fine on the desired page. However, on another page which looks something like this (note the lack of the ID `home-posts`)

```
<div>
   <div class="irrelevantClass">
      <div id="irrelevantID">
         <div class="ClassToTarget">
            2nd load of content
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The '2nd load of content' element is being styled unexpectedly, i.e. to match 'Some content' whereas I do *not* want this element to be styled.

What do I need to change to *stop* the '2nd load of content' area from being styled by the `ClassToTarget` class?

Edit: I am unable to remove or change the name of the `ClassToTarget` on either page, as it is built from a template which I cannot edit.

Addition: On the unwanted page, the `home-posts` ID is being outputted as per this screen shot. Please note for ease of reading I have changed the example ID from `anID` to `home-posts`.
[image: unwanted style]

Comment: should work fine. can you post an example to http://codepen.io showing your problem?

Comment: Remove the `ClassToTarget` class on the other page? Please read how to build a [mcve]. You obviously have other CSS that is affecting your HTML.

Comment: I should have specified that I am unable to remove or change the class name. I should also say that the color:black was just an example style. I'll update my question

Comment: That syntax looks legit, it should work as expected. Make sure that instance of the `id`doesn't occur higher up in the DOM order (i.e: make sure `.ClassToTarget` isn't still a child of `#anID`). Also, try switching up selectors to troubleshoot the issue, or make your selectors more explicit, using the '>' (direct descender) selector.

Comment: I believe you have a `.ClassToTarget` defined somewhere else and this is what is "unexpectedly" styling your element. There's no way your `#anID .ClassToTarget` will style your element unless #anID is parent of `.ClassToTarget` that's just how CSS works.

Comment: The `>` element doesn't add more specificity to a selector @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: @DaniP Yes, you're right, DaniP - I've rephrased

Comment: I'm going to try and do a codepen, in the meantime I think there is a deeper issue. For some reason, on the undesired page, my custom CSS file is outputting `#anID .ClassToTarget {syles}` even though the HTML does *not* have that ID anywhere within it, yet it is still styling the content. (Thanks to everyone so far, much appreciated)

Comment: With the img I can see you have three selectors there `#home-posts .post-name` another on  `.entry-content` and another for `.entry-header` .... how looks your html ?

Comment: Hi Dani, Work in progress (it's very messy at the moment), but here's a code pen of the HTML on the *unwanted* page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMgOxv

Comment: And the HTML on the wanted page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mERdXX

Comment: Ehm, the two codepens are more different than the examples in your post.

Comment: Intentional to try and simplify the situation, which is now a much more complicated situation.